# using django Form subclass to create a dropdown list

Tags: python, django

I need to let a `user` create an Event which has a `Category`.When a user goes to the create_event page he is shown a `dropdown list` of `Category` instances.I need to make sure that only those `Category` s created by the `user` should be shown in the dropdown list

I tried to subclass `Form` for this sothat I can use it as below in view and template.

template for create_event:

```
<h3>select from existing categories</h3>
{{category_choices_form.as_p}}
```

view for create_event:

```
def create_event(request,..):
    user_categories = Category.objects.filter(creator=request.user)
    form_data = get_form_data(request)
    category_choices_form = CategoryChoicesForm(request.user,form_data)# is this correct?
    ...

def get_form_data(request):
    return request.POST if request.method == 'POST' else None
```

Then I created the `Form` subclass

```
class CategoryChoicesForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, categorycreator,*args, **kwargs):
        super(CategoryChoicesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.creator=categorycreator
    categoryoption = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.filter(creator=self.creator),required=False,label='Category')
```

However, the line starting `categoryoption =` causes error saying `name 'self' is not defined`

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a model that you want to expose as an html form, always prefer
to use a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/) instead of a simple form. Unless of course you're doing
a lot of weird or complicated stuff and building a simple form is more straightforward.

So in your situtation

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class CategoryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        # exclude = ('blah', 'foo') # You can exclude fields from your model, if you dont want all of them appearing on your form.
```

Your `get_form_data` function is unnecessary. This is how you use your form in a view

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def create_event(request,..):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CategoryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # do stuff and redirect the user somewhere

    else:
        # We're in a GET request, we just present the form to the user
        form = CategoryForm()
    return render_to_response('some_template.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

---

About the `self is not defined`  error:

in your `CategoryChoicesForm` you have this line

```
    categoryoption = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.filter(creator=self.creator),required=False,label='Category')
```

This is at the class level, when `self` can be used only on an `instance` level. `self` is not "visible" there. It would be visible inside a method of `CategoryChoicesForm` though.

Answer (score 1):

Working with forms you should change query set in this way:

```
class CategoryChoicesForm(forms.Form):
    categoryoption = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                           queryset = Category.objects.none(),
                           required=False,label='Category')

    def __init__(self, categorycreator,*args, **kwargs):
        super(CategoryChoicesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.creator=categorycreator
        self.fields['categoryoption'].queryset = Category.objects.filter( 
                                                           creator=self.creator
                                                                        )
```